# How to get access token Dropbox User IOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, dropbox

I can pretty much do everything with dropbox framework connect,disconnect,download etc.. I want to get access token but following method returns `null`

in one of the .m files

```
//try to get access token
    MPOAuthCredentialConcreteStore *credentials=[[MPOAuthCredentialConcreteStore alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"access token %@",credentials.accessToken);
```

Any idea how can I get users access token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not get accessToken but you can get user info

```
[self.restClient loadAccountInfo];



- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client loadedAccountInfo:(DBAccountInfo*)info {
    NSLog(@"UserID: %@ %@", [info displayName], [info userId]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, U save my time :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get your access token by this delegate.....

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
{

    if ([[DBSession sharedSession] handleOpenURL:url])
    {
        if ([[DBSession sharedSession] isLinked])
        {
            // At this point you can start making API calls

            NSLog(@"App linked successfully!");
    }
    // Add whatever other url handling code your app requires here
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Returned url have Access token, secret token and user id

Comment: The `url` contains an `oauth_token`, `oauth_token_secret`, and a `uid`.